# Zoom is too great in google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nishantnawarkhede/rjJP7/) . Here i have displayed current location and end location by balloons.
And i am trying to put directions between start and end point in the map. In this case no markers for the directions are displayed may be because both shares common location. But the zoom is too great , results in it is not covering start and end point. User have to make double right click to see both start and location.

I have also tried,

```
    new_boundary = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    new_boundary.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(start));
    new_boundary.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(end));
    map.fitBounds(new_boundary);
```

But it is not working. Whats wrong with my map configuration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your script breaks (at least for me) at this line:

```
dir=((Math.atan2(z.lng()-a.lng(),z.lat()-a.lat())*180)/Math.PI)+360
```

take a look at this line:

```
z=(step.lat_lngs.length)?step.lat_lngs[1]:step.end_point,
```

for the first step `lat_lngs.length` is 1 , so `step.lat_lngs[1]` is undefined, the call of `z.lng()` fails with *"Cannot call method 'lng' of undefined"*

Possible fix for that error:

```
z=(step.lat_lngs.length>1)?step.lat_lngs[step.lat_lngs.length-1]:step.end_point,
```

---

**Related to the zoom:**
When you wouldn't have disabled the complete UI you would have seen that the result (zoom ) is correct.

The `DirectionsRenderer` by default will refresh the viewport of the map so that the complete route is visible.
This will be done(the bounds initally set in your script will be discarded).

To have another result(preserve the current viewport, but extend it  that also the route is visible), you must:

1. set the `preserveViewPort`-option of the `DirectionsRenderer` to `true`(default is `false`)
2. extend the bounds of the map with the bounds of the route

---

```
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.set('preserveViewport',true);
        map.fitBounds(map.getBounds().union(response.routes[0].bounds));

        //continue with your code
```

Comment: Thanks , The error `"Cannot call method 'lng' of undefined"` is resolved. Bot not all markers not shown in  map because zoom is too great. How can i adjust zoom level for this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

This code is correct [for example](http://jsfiddle.net/rjJP7/1/)

Your map change resolution when you add

```
 directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
```

> setDirections(directions:DirectionsResult)    None    Set the renderer to
>   use the result from the DirectionsService. Setting a valid set of
>   directions in this manner will display the directions on the
>   renderer's designated map and panel.

Hope, that i understand problem right, English i not my native language

Comment: Thanks , why this is happened ? Due to same start and end point ?

Comment: Cause response contains bounds ((41.30413, -72.92714000000001), (41.30413, -72.92714000000001))  - why is so - i don't know

Comment: Possible points too near ( approximately identical ) - if i change start or/and end coordinates to increase distance - all fine

Comment: Thanks , then which part of code should i skip if two locations are too near ?

Comment: strings 45-45   var start = '41.30395, -72.92671'; // screen location
 var end = '42.3039500,-72.9267090';

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49531/discussion-between-nishant-n-and-vasil-vanchuk)

Comment: Can you please explain this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add validation as

```
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
 if(!response.routes[0].bounds.getNorthEast().equals(response.routes[0].bounds.getSouthWest())){
                 directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);   
                }
                addDirections(response.routes[0]);
            }
        });
```

To check if answer contains different point